# Flickering, lose of focus to textbox, and rate limit reached across network

Tags: bug

If you copy and paste a whole slew of tags in the `Type tags to filter the list` textbox you run into some strange issues when trying to backspace and remove the tags.  So I had a bunch of copied tags and I pasted them in this list and hit enter.  I then started to back space them out one by one (there was a ton of them).  Here's what starts happening:

- Page and ads start flickering.
- In many cases I lose focus on the textbox, and I need to refocus several times.
- The address bar starts changing dynamically (I wonder if it is practical to change it dynamically like we are currently doing).
- Eventually I hit a rate limit and it forced me to contact team@stackoverflow.com.

As I continue to backspace these tags out I always end up losing focus on this textbox, and I have to refocus it. The URL changing in the address bar may be causing this.